# excel macro = link between 2 documents

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I am working on a table(in document A) which needs to be referred to another document(document B, not sheet 2 of document A). I used macro and VLOOKUP to link the data and it works perfectly well when both documents are opened. However, once i closed document B, the data on the table cannot be shown with a message " subscript out of range". 
What can i do to avoid this so that i only have the open the main sheet as to get all my data on the table?

P.S. I created a button which allowed me to click and displayed all the data instantenously. But when i closed document B, only half of the data from Document B were showen and the message subscript out of range" was shown.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open both docs, then FIRST close B (and save), THEN close A (saving).
Now reopen A, it should ask you if you want to update the links. Reply Yes. That should be it.
If you're using 2007, you may have to expressely allow external data updates.